# Find the index of element in list

Tags: list, scheme, element

I need to get index of element in list in scheme. For example:

> > (... 2 '(2 3 4 5))
> >
> > 0
> >
> > (... 4 '(2 3 4 5))
> >
> > 2

Can someone help?

Comment: Have you tried something? Also, which language do you use?

Comment: scheme, I have this:

(define map-index-pred
  (lambda (pred? f l)
    (foldr (lambda (x y)
             (if (pred? x)
                 (cons (f x) y)
                 (cons x y)))
           '()
           l)))
(map-index-pred odd? sqr '(2 3 4 5))
(map-index-pred (lambda(i) (< i 2)) - '(1 2 3 4 5))

it works only for the numbers (x), I need it for their indexes... :(

Answer (score -1, accepted):

my final solution:

```
(define index
  (lambda (cislo l)
    (if (equal? (car l) cislo) 0 (+ 1 (index cislo (cdr l))))))
(define map-index-pred
  (lambda (pred? f l)
     (foldr (lambda (x y)
       (if (pred? (index x l))
         (cons (f x) y) (cons x y))) '() l)))
```

Comment: Your index method isn't tail recursive. With big lists it could give problems.

Answer (score 9):

Somthing like this

```
(define list-index
        (lambda (e lst)
                (if (null? lst)
                        -1
                        (if (eq? (car lst) e)
                                0
                                (if (= (list-index e (cdr lst)) -1) 
                                        -1
                                        (+ 1 (list-index e (cdr lst))))))))
```

Answer (score 6):

The following is the clearest solution I could come up with:

```
(define (get-list-index l el)
    (if (null? l)
        -1
        (if (= (car l) el)
            0
            (let ((result (get-list-index (cdr l) el)))
                (if (= result -1)
                    -1
                    (1+ result))))))
```

This solution is largely the same as merriav's except that I've added a let at the end so that the recursive call is not unnecessarily repeated (in written code or execution).

The accepted solution does not seem to account for an empty list, or a list that does not contain the element being sought after.

Answer (score 3):

You could implement *index* using *reverse*, *member*, *length*, and *cdr* as follows:

```
(define (index a b)
  (let [(tail (member a (reverse b)))]
    (and tail (length (cdr tail))))
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer was easier than you guys expected, also without recursion :)

Simple function, in case you are sure the element is in the list

```
(define element-index
  (lambda (elemento lista)
    (- (length lista) (length (memv elemento lista)))))
```

If you consider the case where the element may not be in the list. Return `false` if not found

```
(define element-index
  (lambda (elemento lista)
    (if (eqv? (list? (memv elemento lista)) #t)
        (- (length lista) (length (memv elemento lista)))
        false
        )
    ))
```

Final result:

```
> (element-index 2 '(2 3 4 5))
0
> (element-index 4 '(2 3 4 5))
2
> (element-index 6 '(2 3 4 5))
false
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code achieves the objective :

```
(define (getpos element lst)
    (let loop ([counter 0] [temp lst])
        (if (= element (car temp)) counter
            (loop (+ counter 1) (cdr temp)))))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to worry about the case that the element is not in the list, the following code is probably the shortest version. (An exception will occur if the element is not in the list.)

```
(define (element-index e lst)
    (cond [(eqv? e (car lst)) 0]
          [else (+ (element-index e (cdr lst)) 1)])))
```

Otherwise, use the following code:

```
(define element-index
  (letrec
    ([element-index-helper
       (lambda (e lst index)
         (cond [(null? lst) #f]
               [(eqv? e (car lst)) index]
               [else (element-index-helper e (cdr lst) (+ index 1))]))])
    (lambda (e lst)
      (element-index-helper e lst 0))))
```

Examples:

```
> (element-index 'a '(a b c))
0
> (element-index 'b '(a b c))
1
> (element-index 'c '(a b c))
2
> (element-index 'd '(a b c))
#f
```