# Position of element in List

Tags: list, elm

I'm trying to get the index of an element in a list given its Id. This is what I have:

```
type alias Id = Int  

posInList : Id -> List (Id, ItemModel) -> Int
posInList id list =
  if List.isEmpty list then 
      -1
  else 
    if (List.head list).fst == id then
      0
    else 
      if posInList id (List.tail list) == -1 then
        -1
      else
        posInList id (List.tail list) + 1
```

I got that from scheme-code found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13562200/find-the-index-of-element-in-list) (answer with 7 votes).

When I compile the code I get two errors:

[image: type-mismatch]
[image]

How do I solve this? Or is there a simpler solution?

**Update: tried it with Maybe**

```
posInList : Id -> Maybe List (Id, ItemModel) -> Int
posInList id list =
  case list of
    Nothing -> -1
    Just a -> 
      case (List.head a) of
        Just b -> 
          if b.fst == id then 
            0
          else
            case (List.tail a) of
              Nothing -> -1
              Just c -> (posInList id (Just c)) + 1
        Nothing -> -1
```

I think I'm close but I can't resolve this error:

[image: just-c]

`Just c` is of type `Maybe List` but where does that conflict with `Maybe`?
I thought the type annotation so I added brackets like so:

```
posInList : Id -> Maybe (List (Id, ItemModel)) -> Int
```

But then I get:

[image]

And now I'm clueless, never seen an error like that.

Comment: `(List.head list).fst` I think List.head returns an element not a list. Try without calling `.fst`

Comment: Where is your maybe type declared? i.e. there is no reference to it in the function signature... And why are you adding 1 to the list?

Comment: `Maybe` is a core type in ELM: http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/3.0.0/Maybe

Comment: Sure, but it still has a signature. Do you have any experience with haskell?

Comment: Yes, a little bit, I've tried it with Maybe, updated the post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First it may help to break it down into a simpler `indexOf` function to avoid having to deal with the specific tuple model you're using. This makes it a little cleaner and more reusable.

We'll define `indexOf` as this:

```elm
indexOf : a -> List a -> Maybe Int
indexOf el list =
  let
    indexOf' list' index =
      case list' of
        [] ->
          Nothing
        (x::xs) ->
          if x == el then
            Just index
          else
            indexOf' xs (index + 1)
  in
    indexOf' list 0
```

There's nothing special going on here, it's just pattern matching and a recursive call. The sub-function, `indexOf'` is used to keep track of the current index.

Now we have a general purpose `indexOf` function that can be used on any comparable type, not just integers.

Next we need to squeeze in your list of type `List (Id, ItemModel)`. This is where we can use `fst` in the `map` function, creating a list of `Id`s.

```elm
posInList : Id -> List (Id, ItemModel) -> Int
posInList id list =
  case indexOf id (List.map fst list) of
    Nothing ->
      -1
    Just index ->
       index
```

Your original implementation was returning -1 in the case when something is not found, but I think it would be more idiomatic to return a `Maybe Int` instead. That would make it clear what your intention was to anyone else using the library.

Answer (score 0):

Update of [@Chad Gilbert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/34409/chad-gilbert)'s great response, as of 2023.

Single quotes `'` are not allowed in variable names since [Elm version 0.18](https://elm-lang.org/news/the-perfect-bug-report) (Nov 2016).

Function `fst` was moved (and renamed) to [Tuple.first](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/core/latest/Tuple#first) in [Oct 2016](https://github.com/elm/core/commit/6b72fa57cb684c3c69c61a82410894f0303462ad).

Also the general function indexOf is implemented in the community package [list-extra](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-community/list-extra/latest) under the name [elemIndex](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-community/list-extra/latest/List-Extra#elemIndex), so you don't need to implement it yourself, unless you want to.

Lastly, the solution may look like this:

```
import List.Extra exposing (elemIndex)
import Maybe exposing (withDefault)
import Tuple exposing (first)


posInList : Id -> List ( Id, ItemModel ) -> Int
posInList id list =
    List.map first list |> elemIndex id >> withDefault -1
```

Same as [@Chad Gilbert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/34409/chad-gilbert), I would also returned `Maybe Int` rather than `Int` (with default -1).
In that case, just remove the  `>> withDefault -1` from the last line (and change the signature to `Maybe Int`).